# Why is $U_e=-W$?

Tags: electric-fields, work, potential-energy

Electric potential energy $U_e$ is defined as $k_e\frac{Q_1Q_2}{r}$. From that we get:
$$U_e=k_e\frac{Q_1Q_2}{r}=ErQ_2=F_er=W$$
Now, a lot of sources claim that $U_e=-W$. Why is work negative in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the definitions backwards. The potential energy of a system of 2 charges is **defined** to be the negative of the work, $W$, done *by the field* of one charge ($Q_1$) acting on the other charge, $Q_2$, as it changes position (how it changes is irrelevant) from infinity to some finite separation distance, $r$,
\begin{align}U_e &=-W= -\int_{\infty}^r \vec{F}\cdot (\hat{r} \mathrm{d}r). \\
 &= -\int_{\infty}^r k_e \frac{Q_1 Q_2}{r^2}\hat{r}\cdot (\hat{r} \mathrm{d}r). \\
 &= - k_e\left(\left.-\frac{Q_1Q_2}{r}\right|_{\infty}^r\right)\\
 U_e &= k_e\frac{Q_1Q_2}{r} 
\end{align}
So we see that the potential energy, defined by the work, gives the *result*  that you stated as a definition.

And the reason your formula train didn't work is because you missed some negative signs in dealing with vector quantities.

Answer (score 1):

$U_e$ is the work done by force you exerted but $W$ is the work done by force of electric field. The relation of $U_e$ and $W$ is
$$U_e=-W$$